# OpenGLRenderer, found invalid glyph

Tags: android, listview

I am trying on an android application which have a listview in it.
In this listview, just images are listed.

I wonder, although application works perfectly, when i click on an item in listview sometimes an error log appears : "**found invalid glyph**". (I'm using *Eclipse ADT Bundle*.)

Do anyone have an idea about it ?

Regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That error log most likely comes from hwui/FontRenderer.cpp ([see here](https://code.google.com/p/cloa/source/browse/trunk/qrd_qs/frameworks/base/libs/hwui/FontRenderer.cpp?r=2)).

Good news is that it probably shouldn't be logged as an error, but a warning instead. It simply means the character wasn't cached when it was supposed to be rendered. If it were a bigger problem, you would see a "still found invalid glyph" error after.